# Terminology - Union of kernels of iterated linear functions

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

Quick question:

- if $V$ is a $K$-vector space,
- $f : V \to V$ a linear function and
- $f^k = f \circ \ldots \circ f$ ($k$ times),

does $\mathscr U = \displaystyle \bigcup_{k\ge 1} \ker f^k$ have an usual name?

Given that the kernels are a growing series, $\mathscr U$ is obviously a subspace of $V$; I was wondering if there was a corpus of generic properties for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general if $f\in \operatorname{End}(V)$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, then the space $\ker(f-\lambda\,\mathit{Id})$ is called the *eigenspace* of $\lambda$ and sometimes $\bigcup_{k>0}\ker(f-\lambda\,\mathit{Id})^k$ is called the *generalized eigenspace* of $\lambda$.

Thus your space is the generalized eigenspace of $0$.

These objects are used to build the so-called Jordan Normal Form of $f$.
[See for instance here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if these things have been studied in dimension $\infty$? I was just thinking that if $V$ is the set of $C^{\infty}$ functions and $f$ is the derivation operator, $\mathscr U$ is exactly the set of polynomial functions.

Comment: in dimension $\infty$ one has a lot of spectral theory (the "easy" case when the endomorphism is diagonalizable). In full generality I don't know what's known exactly and what are the analogues of the Jordan Normal Form. For particular properties, it depends of what you need. For instance, the facts that $\ker f^k\leq\ker f^{k+1}$ and that if $\ker f=\ker f^{k+1}$ then $\ker f^k=\ker f^{k+n} \forall n$ do not depend on the finte dimension assumption.

Comment: by the way, the derivative is an unbounded operator, so I suspect that it has no good "spectral properties". (polynomials are dense, so one may hope that the only eigenvalue is zero, but then you have $e^x$ which is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $1$...) But I'm not a specialist